# Springfox swagger java.time.LocalDate issue

Tags: java, swagger-2.0

I use springfox-swagger2 2.7.0.

I have @ApiModel with Date field (java.util.Date). I want to generate swagger.json with format: date. I know that java.util.Date is in fact date-time so I use @ApiModelProperty (dataType=...) and then there is problem:

- When I use dataType="java.time.LocalDate", swagger.json shows
  $ref:"#/definitions/LocalDate" which is wrong
- When I use dataType="LocalDate" I have date-time which is wrong
- When I use dataType="org.joda.time.LocalDate" I have date-time which
  is wrong
- When I use dataType="java.sql.Date" I have desired date format

I can use java.sql.Date but I prefer java.time.LocalDate. Is there some bug in swagger or maybe I have to add some other code for that to work properly?